# What is the purpose of specifying a schema in a web xml?

Tags: xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, schema, dtd

Data Type Definition (DTD) and XML Schema Definition (XSD) - These are the two type of specifying a schema in a web xml. What is the purpose of a specifying this exactly?

I have specified this in my TestNG.xml file like this

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
```

What is the purpose of testng-1.0.dtd here?

I got some information here on DTD but I really don't understand the purpose of adding this in the XML file? 
http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd.php

Any help in explaining this is much appreciated. I am building a test automation framework using Selenium WebDriver and using this in my TestNG.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one of the basic use is when you are using any IDE code complete feature then DTD will help you to complete your code.

i.e.

if you are using  tag but not sure of spelling or its atributes then you can rite < and press Ctrl+Space Bar , you will find code complete.

its a kind of xmldoc , counterpart of javadoc

Comment: Thanks, @Bhupesh. So it's basically an IDE code-complete feature which autocompletes the attributes of a tag.

Comment: it is not limited to a IDE code complete feature. With its help IDE provide you code complete feature but actually it is providing legal and correct structure (or you can say correct syntax ) to your xml. If at the time of creation of the xml you are not following the structure from its DTD file your xml will not work correctly.

For example , For your testNg.xml file the corresponding dtd file data will look like the data in http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd.php

When you open this urlin browser you will see different condition in this file which are required to follow in testng.xml file.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand the purpose of DTD now :)